# MIPS jump loop - high order error

Tags: mips

I cannot seem to get this right for some reason, I googled it a bunch too, but could not find a solution for this. I am getting the error:"Target of jump differs in high-order 4 bits from instruction pc 0x400054". I tried to jump in an increment of 2 jumps to reach the goal, but it still will not work. Am I doing something wrong? I am trying to jump to the `loop:` section.. Is there any way that I can do this?

```
.text
.globl main
main: 
loop:           la          $a0, celsius        #String celsius
                li          $v0,   4
                syscall

                li          $v0,   5            #Read int celsius 
                syscall
                j           one
backone:        j           loop    
one:            blt         $v0, -50, end       #tests if in bounds, else out
                bgt         $v0,  50, end
                jal         celsius
                nop
                j           backone             #I was getting "Target of jump differs in high-order 4 bits from instruction pc 0x40004c"
end:            li          $v0,  10            #so I just inserted 2 jumps.

.data
celsius: .asciiz "/nEnter in celsius: "

.text
.globl compute
compute:
                move        $a0, $v0 
                mul         $a0, $a0,  9
                div         $a0, $a0,  5 
                addu        $a0, $a0, 32
                move        $t0, $a0

                la          $a0, degrees        #print degrees:
                li          $v0, 4
                syscall

                move        $a0, $t0            #Print int
                li          $v0, 1
                syscall

                jr          $ra                 #returns
                nop

.data
degrees: .asciiz "\nDegrees Fahrenheit: "
```

Comment: If you're jumping inside of a function, you'll probably avoid trouble by using `b` instead of `j`.

Comment: Isn't the j outside of the function though?

Comment: You can always use `b` to unconditionally branch to a target ~ +/- 2^15 instructions from the `b`. Unless your `main:`-function is larger than that, just `b loop`. If you want to know *why* `j` doesn't work, read the instruction set manual.

Comment: `jal celsius` is trying to jump to a location in the `.data` segment. You probably meant to say `jal compute`.

Comment: @markgz: \*sigh\* I love accurately reported assembler errors.

Comment: Thank you... I honestly spent 5 hours straight trying to figure ou what I did... that compiler error didn't suggest anything that I understood